# titleView of Navigation item moved to the left?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have an app with a left (hamburger) `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` and we've set the `titleView` to the logo of the company. The problem is that they want the logo next to the hamburger. The hamburger button is set in the Storyboard's `ViewController` and the logo is programmatically, like this:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 60)
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Is there a way to move it to the left?

**UPDATE:** 
Regarding the suggestions to use `leftBarButtonItems`

I've done this in another `UIViewController` and the result wasn't as I expected it to be. 
Here's the code:

```
let logo    = UIImage(named: "logo")!
let karambaButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: logo,  style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
let backBTN = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: navigationController, action: #selector(UINavigationController.popViewController(animated:)))

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [backBTN, logoButton]
```

And here's the result of it:

[image]

(The dark block is the image, I had to cover it up because it's a client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set multiple left bar button items by acessing:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [barItem1, barItem2]
```

Same with the right side. :)

Comment: I've actually done that and there's a huge gap in between (its another view controller but ive tried this approach)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32473989/11138557 
you can try this one for the spacing issue.

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationItem has a property named [`leftBarButtonItems`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624946-leftbarbuttonitems).

Put your logo imageView into the customView property of a UIBarItem and [size it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988918/change-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-a-uinavigationbar/13693015) and you should be all set.   Just add it to the the array along with the hamburger button.

edited to add -- try using a custom view, that is:

```
if let logo = UIImage(named: "logo") {

  let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)

  let karambaButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)

  let backBTN = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: navigationController,
action: #selector(UINavigationController.popViewController(animated:)))

  navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [backBTN, logoButton]

}
```

Comment: Can you please see the updated question. I've added information regarding your suggestion. It still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can also set auto layout programmatically.

```
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let horizontalConstraint = imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hamburgerButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 10)
    let verticalConstraint = newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hamburgerButton.centerYAnchor)
    let widthConstraint = newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120)
    let heightConstraint = newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120)
    imageView.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
```