# UiNavigationController - title in navigation bar is off-center when right side has 2 buttons

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm using a UINvagigationController for my app, with every page setting their own title and left and right buttons.
Worked perfectly until I needed two buttons to the right. Just setting them as bar button items throws the title off-center, and the space between them is way bigger then expected:
[image]

This is how I set up those buttons to the right:

```
    let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.btnGoToScan)
    let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.btnExportImage)
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1, item2], animated: false)
```

I have tried setting the width of those items, as well as adding fixed space of negative width between them - changes nothing:

```
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.btnGoToScan)
    item1.width = 24
    let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.btnExportImage)
    item2.width = 24
    let negativeSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    negativeSpace.width = -16
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1, negativeSpace, item2], animated: false)
```

How can I make the right bar items close and the title always centered? Like this:
[image]

Edit:
That's how the bar looks with a short title:
[image]

The title is thankfully centered for it, but the spacing around buttons on the right is way too big.

Edit 2:
Tried the solution from [navigation bar right bar button items spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457080/navigation-bar-right-bar-button-items-spacing?rq=1) - did not work. Did not change the look of navigation bar in the slightest, whatever frame size I tried to set.

Comment: Doesn't your second picture already answer your question? A short title is centered because it fits. A long title isn't centered because it doesn't fit.

Comment: @HangarRash
First, the second picture is the desired outcome, NOT what actually happens with the title. Second, that's exactly the problem - both titles should be centered. Third - is it possible to make the distance between buttons smaller, like on the second pic?

Comment: @Afinainflowers - You have an "X" button instead of a "Back" button... is this a **pushed** controller? Is it a **presented** controller? Are you using push/pop navigation within this view?

Comment: @DonMag this is a pushed controller inside a UINavigationController. Back button is hidden, "X" button is set up as a left bar button item.

Comment: @Afinainflowers Your desire to center longer titles makes little sense. It would result in being able to see a lot less of the title.

Comment: @HangarRash Can the buttons to the right at least be moved closer together, so they will take up less space? They are square, there is no need to space them out that much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [navigation bar right bar button items spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457080/navigation-bar-right-bar-button-items-spacing)

Comment: @Afinainflowers - assuming your 3 current buttons are equal widths, add a clear view with the same width and set `self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([itemXbutton, itemClear], animated: false)` ?

Comment: @HangarRash please read the question in full - I added in the end that I've tried this solution and it did nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can center the title by using two buttons on each side - with the 2nd button on the left being a "blank" button...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Example code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        guard let img1 = UIImage(named: "nav1"),
              let img2 = UIImage(named: "nav2"),
              let img3 = UIImage(named: "nav3")
        else { fatalError() }
        
        let b1 = UIButton()
        let b2 = UIButton()
        let b3 = UIButton()
        let b4 = UIButton()
        
        b1.setImage(img1, for: [])
        b2.setImage(img2, for: [])
        b3.setImage(img3, for: [])
        // b4 - no image

        // all buttons set to 24x24
        [b1, b2, b3, b4].forEach { v in
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24.0).isActive = true
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: b1)
        let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: b2)

        let item3 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: b3)
        let item4 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: b4)
        
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1, item2], animated: false)
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([item3, item4], animated: false)

        self.title = "This Test Title will be Truncated"

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The title length in your sample and desired outcome is significantly different.

If the title is short enough iOS will try and put it in the centre automatically. Although if the title doesn't fit iOS tries to squeeze it in thus shifting it to the left.

Try out your code with a shorter title — most likely it will work like expected.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Plus, the OP already shows that a short title is centered. See the last picture in the question.

Comment: @HangarRash The second picture is the desired outcome, NOT what actually happens with the title.

Comment: @Afinainflowers But your newly added 3rd picture does show that a short title is centered. So that does mean that the 2nd picture shows what happens with a shorter title. The key difference now is the button spacing.